# C#: Set Brightness for phone Windows Phone 8.1 camera

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I was trying to change the Windows phone Camera Brightness

I Have tried this code

```
private async Task StartCapture()
    {
                mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

                var _deviceInformation = await GetCameraDeviceInfoAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);

                var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
                settings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video;
                settings.PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview;
                settings.AudioDeviceId = "";
                if (_deviceInformation != null)
                    settings.VideoDeviceId = _deviceInformation.Id;

                await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
                mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.Brightness.TrySetValue(50);



            captureReceipt.Source = mediaCapture;
            await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();


    }

    private static async Task<DeviceInformation> GetCameraDeviceInfoAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel desiredPanel)
    {

        DeviceInformation device = (await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture))
            .FirstOrDefault(d => d.EnclosureLocation != null && d.EnclosureLocation.Panel == desiredPanel);


        return device;
    }
```

And the Xaml is :

```
<Grid>
    <CaptureElement x:Name="captureReceipt"/>
</Grid>
```

But i was not able to alter the brightness of the camera

Is there any way i could change the brightness of windows phone camera?

Comment: Please reduce your sample code down to just the part you're having trouble with. At the moment, it contains far too much irrelevant code.

Comment: hi I'm having the same problem, could you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Check the values in mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.Brightness.Capabilities.

Are Supported and AutoModeSupported set to true? What are the values for Min, Max and Default?

Comment: ok so i checked Are Supported is true while AutoModeSupported is false